# D3: Append duplicates of a selection

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'd like to create a javascript function which can take a generic D3 selection, and append duplicates of it to an SVG object.

Here's a minimum working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                         .attr("width", 300)
                         .attr("height", 300);

circle = svg.append("circle")
              .attr("cx", 100)
              .attr("cy", 100)
              .attr("r", 20)

function clone_selection(x, i) {
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    // Pseudo code:
    // svg.append(an exact copy of x, with all the attributes)
  }
}

clone_selection(circle, 5);
</script>
```

Mike Bostock said that this was impossible [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/wKxCRYvcx-I) but that was a while back.

Does anyone have any new thoughts about how this might be achieved? Remember, inside the function `clone_selection` we have no idea what svg element(s) is/are in x.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`cloneNode`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp)?

Comment: Do you need a true clone, or would <use> elements work?

Comment: Thanks for both comments. Neither of these works with a generic D3 selection, though. There's more conversation about this [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/732#issuecomment-7390693) but I suppose the selection.clone() method Mike Bostock mentions hasn't yet been implemented.

Comment: @nrabinowitz I actually want a shallow copy of an object, rather than a clone. That makes <use> elements appropriate, right? I can presumably do `svg.selectAll("use").data(someData).enter().append().attr("xlink:href","#myID")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's another possibility: do things the long way. This gets round the problem with using `<use>` elements where you can't set the `style` or `transform` attributes separately.

I'm surprised the amazing `d3js` library doesn't feature something like this natively, but here's my hack:

```
function clone_d3_selection(selection, i) {
            // Assume the selection contains only one object, or just work
            // on the first object. 'i' is an index to add to the id of the
            // newly cloned DOM element.
    var attr = selection.node().attributes;
    var length = attr.length;
    var node_name = selection.property("nodeName");
    var parent = d3.select(selection.node().parentNode);
    var cloned = parent.append(node_name)
                 .attr("id", selection.attr("id") + i);
    for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) { // Iterate on attributes and skip on "id"
        if (attr[j].nodeName == "id") continue;
        cloned.attr(attr[j].name,attr[j].value);
    }
    return cloned;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @nrabinowitz for pointing me to `<use>` elements.

Here's the MWE complete with working solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
             .attr("width", 300)
             .attr("height", 300);

circle = svg.append("circle")
          .attr("id", "circleToClone")
          .attr("cx", 100)
          .attr("cy", 100)
          .attr("r", 20)

function clone_selection(object, i) {
  for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    // Here's the solution:
    cloned_obj = svg.append("use")
                .attr("xlink:href","#" + object.attr("id"));
  }
}

clone_selection(circle, 5);
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm.. I've just tested this and it turns out that this method is not ideal, because you can't apply `style` or `transform` attributes to `<use>` objects. That means you're stuck with genuine copies of the initial object. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Hmm - I'm pretty sure you can override attributes like `fill`, `cx`, `cy`, etc on the `use` element. I'm surprised you can't use `transform`, but you could always wrap the element in a `g` with a transform and style applied.

Comment: This is the better answer as far as I found, as well.


@LondonRob, As far as being unable to override fill, cx, cy, etc, I found that if the original svg has any of these defined, you can't override it.  But if you leave that intentionally blank on the original, you can put whatever attributes you want.

Comment: @Phil if you want this to be the top answer, upvote it and it will be!

Answer (score 5):

This function makes a deep copy of d3's selection and returns the selection of copied elements:

```
function cloneSelection(appendTo, toCopy, times) {
  toCopy.each(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        var clone = svg.node().appendChild(this.cloneNode(true));
        d3.select(clone).attr("class", "clone");
    }
  });
  return appendTo.selectAll('.clone');
}
```

See demo [here](http://jsbin.com/filaqoqidu/1/edit?css,js,output).

This function works also if the selection toCopy contains multiple elements.

But be aware, that it copies everything, along with classes, ids and other attributes of all inner elements, which might break your code, if you're directly referencing inner elements somewhere else. So keep an eye on your selections. Having a parent, that distinguishes clone from the original, and mentioning it in the selection chain will keep you safe.

A reasonable thing to do (if you really need id so much) is to have id set only on the outer element of what you're copying, where you can easily change it by modifying the function: `d3.select(clone).attr("class", "clone").attr("id", "clone-" + i)`.

Answer (score 3):

And 4 years and 4 month later... I made this D3 plugin.
https://github.com/jkutianski/d3-clone

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late to answer, but while I developed my own solution I found this question. This is how I create duplicates.

```
    d3.select("#some_id")
      .append("div")
      .attr("class","some_other_id")
      .each(function(d) {

    for (var i = 1; i < number_duplicate; i++) {
        d3.select("#some_other_id")
          .append("button")
          .attr("type","button")
          .attr("class","btn-btn")
          .attr("id","id_here")
          .append("div")
          .attr("class","label")
          .text("text_here")


    }
});
```

I create a div, do .each() on it and put a for loop into the each function.
The number some_number will give me the intended amount of duplicates.

Variations will be possible, probably a second for would work etc. Maybe a poor man's version - I am not a pro. I would like to hear your feed back.